# APS Configurator cant find entity

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Has anyone ever had a problem finding a signed surface through APS? I use it to add dimensions. Everything works fine in Inventor, but when I upload it to APS, I receive the following error:

Details: Autodesk.iLogic.InventorHostException: GetIntent: No drawing curves found for entity "Plaszczyzna1" in component "DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA, BLACHA_SRODEK" in view "A".
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]  Exception of type 'Autodesk.iLogic.NoDrawingCurvesException' was thrown.
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Core.ManagedDrawing.GeometryIntentHelper.GetGeometryIntent(DrawingView view, String parameterName, Boolean mayReturnCenterMark, Centermark& outCM)
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Core.ManagedDrawing.ManagedDrawingView.GetIntent(ComponentArgument component, String entityName, PointIntentEnum intent, CurveChoiceSpec nearPoint)
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]    at ThisRule.Main()
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[11/06/2023 10:57:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error

My code looks like:

'[ widok A

```
Dim Plaszczyzna1 = WIDOKA.GetIntent({"DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA", "BLACHA_FRONT"}, "Plaszczyzna1")
Dim Krawedz5 = WIDOKA.GetIntent({"DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA", "BLACHA_LEWA_PRAWA" }, "Krawedz5")
polozenieWymiaruWidokA_1 = oTG.CreatePoint2d((WIDOKA.Center.X) / 10, (WIDOKA.Center.Y) / 10 + 3)
Dim linDim3 = genDims.AddLinear(polozenieWymiaruWidokA_1, Plaszczyzna1, Krawedz5)

Dim Plaszczyzna2 = WIDOKA.GetIntent({"DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA", "BLACHA_FRONT" }, "Plaszczyzna1") 
Dim Plaszczyzna3 = WIDOKA.GetIntent({"DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA", "BLACHA_SRODEK"}, "Plaszczyzna1") 
polozenieWymiaruWidokA_2 = oTG.CreatePoint2d((WIDOKA.Center.X) / 10, (WIDOKA.Center.Y) / 10 - 3)
Dim linDim4 = genDims.AddLinear(polozenieWymiaruWidokA_2, Plaszczyzna2, Plaszczyzna3)

Dim Krawedz6 = WIDOKA.GetIntent({"DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA", "BLACHA_LEWA_PRAWA"}, "Krawedz4")
Dim Krawedz7 = WIDOKA.GetIntent({"DELTA_CORNER_PUSZKA", "BLACHA_LEWA_PRAWA" }, "Krawedz6")
```

I tried:

Change the name of the plane.
The only solution is to comment out the line of code that assigns this plane to the variable.

Comment: I assume it's the same issue you contacted me about and you managed to figure out in the end?

Comment: Yeah it was the same issue. I fixed it.